# Angular 2 project to Angular 4 update issue

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I have recently upgraded my Angular 2 project to Angular 4 ,after going through this official link ([Update to Angular 4](https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/)).

After upgrading,as i am running my Angular app following error is coming and saying my `package.json` file is having some issues.

[image: Updation errors]

Comment: Angular4 will support only TypeScript 2.1 and above.. make sure you have updated same as well

Comment: did you 'rimraf node_mdules' and then 'npm install' ?

Comment: @anoop i have updated typescript to 2.2 and done npm install ,npm start..same issue

Comment: @kuncevic 'rimraf node_mdules' means..?

Comment: as @Kuncevic suggested, try to delete your `node_modules` folder and do npm install again.

Comment: Follow the official Angular Update Guide. https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps to update application from angular 2 to angular 4.

1) Delete your node modules

2) Update your dependency 
In Linux Enviroment

```
npm install @angular/{
    animations,
    common,
    compiler,
    compiler-cli,
    core,
    forms,
    http,
    platform-browser,
    platform-browser-dynamic,
    platform-server,
    router
}@4.0.0 typescript@latest --save
```

now serve your app using `ng serve` or `npm start`

If you are using Animations, import `BrowserAnimationsModule` in your root NgModule using

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from @angular/platform-browser/animations
```

If you still facing problem then you read from angular [Release Note](http://angularjs.blogspot.in/2017/03/angular-400-now-available.html) or you can refer this [link](http://www.zippyout.com/blog/58ef4a541c08d96199ae8a58/angular-4-release-notes-and-how-to-update-angular-2-application-to-angular-4)

Comment: I believe he is running windows so option number 2 won't work for him unless he is running `bash`

Answer (score 2):

You can Update by this command if you are using Ubuntu.

```
npm install @angular/common@next @angular/compiler@next @angular/compiler-cli@next @angular/core@next @angular/forms@next @angular/http@next @angular/platform-browser@next @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@next @angular/platform-server@next @angular/router@next @angular/animations@next --save
```

Hope this will help you.

[Reference website](https://www.technologyshouters.com/install-angular-4-ubuntu-step-step-complete-guide/)

Answer (score 1):

```
"devDependencies": {
  "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
  "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
  "typescript": "2.3.4",
  "typings": "^1.3.2"
}
```

Change typescript version "typescript": "^2.4.0" to "typescript": "^2.3.4" and then command **npm install** version will be change, and also **rxjs** version will be **"rxjs": "^5.4.2"** in **package.json.** Then run command **ng serve** it's working. Then you can check your angular version in 
element.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your `package.json` if it contains all the right packages. Make sure that you're running the latest typescript.
2. Try to reinstall your npm modules:

   ```
   npm install rimraf -g
   rimraf node_modules 
   npm install
   ```

Answer (score 0):

While installing the latest node version, first uninstall the older version of node, and manually remove all the node related files from its installation path and try install newer version of node js. Then run "npm clear cache" command as well.

The angular-cli global npm package names are different for angular2 and angular4.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Package.json and tsconfig.json contents. For content refer [here](http://icodefy.com/upgrade-application-from-angular-2-to-angular-4/)
delete all the files inside node module. 
run the command "npm install && npm update && npm start".